# How to create cocoa-pod of a Objective-C framework?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a framework of which I want to create cocoapods. I am using that framework in several projects. Kindly tell how can i create cocoapods of a FRAMEWORK.

So its like I have my Xcode proj ready and framework and also git. But how to create cocoapod of it.

Comment: Any suggestion ?? I am getting compilation error when using CocoaPods inside project (for creating Framework).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190643/656600